# How to correctly scope a dataframe in R to use with a formula in a function

Tags: r, function, survival-analysis, scoping

After some digging ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834649/fix-survival-environment-error-in-is-data-frame-error-using-pryr-or-other-ti), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738045/in-r-error-in-is-data-framedata-object-not-found-c5-0-plot), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514482/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found-with-xyplot)), there appears to be a few posts about using formulas within functions causing scoping issues if I am understanding them correctly. Some suggests to use an environment, assign, or `<<-` to get around the issue, but I've been stumped how to use them (and confused why there's an issue in the first place).

Let's try this toy code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
set.seed(1)

give_p_val <- function() {
  df <- data.frame('OS' = ovarian[, 'futime'], 'Survival_event' = ovarian[, 'fustat'])
  subgroup <- sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)/2)
  df$Class <- 'A'
  df$Class[subgroup] <- 'B'
  
  fit2 <- survfit(Surv(OS, Survival_event) ~ Class, data=df) 
  return(surv_pvalue(fit2))
}
give_p_val( )
```

It doesn't work, unless you run it directly, which hints at a scoping issue.

This code will work to return a fitted object:

```
survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data=ovarian)
```

So why does the function break if we copy a dataframe within the scope?

```
testit<-function(){
  ovarian2 <- ovarian
  fit2 <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data=ovarian2)
  return(surv_pvalue(fit2))
}
  
testit()
```

Ultimately, how do I generate a dataframe within a function to be handled correctly by the formula being used?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/547) in the `survminer` package and how `surv_pvalue` interacts with `survfit` objects. If you change `survfit` to  the `survminer` package's version, `surv_fit`, your function will work just fine.

```
give_p_val <- function() {
  df <- data.frame('OS' = ovarian[, 'futime'], 'Survival_event' = ovarian[, 'fustat'])
  subgroup <- sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)/2)
  df$Class <- 'A'
  df$Class[subgroup] <- 'B'
  fit2 <- surv_fit(Surv(OS, Survival_event) ~ Class, data=df) 
  surv_pvalue(fit2, data = df)
}
give_p_val( )
#   variable      pval   method pval.txt
# 1    Class 0.2615363 Log-rank p = 0.26
```

Comment: I looked at the exposed code of `surv_fit`. An impressive sequence of tests and conditional branching with either error reporting or dispatch to one of two hidden `.survfit` functions.